# Translate Qt QML application on the fly

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to translate a qt QML application that is filled with

```
tr("string");
```

All over the place, If I set the translator before the app starts it works perfectly, but I'm having troubles doing it on the fly. The only solution seems to be the [empty string hack](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML) but I dont want to search for every "tr" and add the empty string

Comment: Are you using `tr` (from C++) or `qsTr` (from qml)?

Comment: @m7913d I'm using it from both

Comment: "but I dont want to search for every "tr" and add the empty string". 
Tough luck. Gotta wait for that sweet 5.10 release then.

Answer (score 5):

**Up to Qt 5.9**, the easiest solution is to add an empty string to each translatable string: [How to do dynamic translation in QML](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML)

**From Qt 5.10**, it is possible to retranslate all strings by calling: [`QQmlEngine::retranslate`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qqmlengine.html#retranslate)

More information can be found in the [QtQuick Internationalization](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qtquick-internationalization.html#9-prepare-for-dynamic-language-changes) documentation:

> You can change the language that Qt translation functions use by
>   adding and removing translators with
>   `QCoreApplication::installTranslator()` and
>   `QCoreApplication::removeTranslator()`. Afterwards you can call
>   `QQmlEngine::retranslate()` to trigger a refresh of all bindings that
>   use translations. As a result, your user interface will switch,
>   dynamically, to the newly selected language.
>
> Alternatively, you can also forward a `QEvent::LanguageChange` event to
>   your application's QQmlEngine instance or connect your own signal to `QQmlEngine::retranslate()`.

*Note that at the time of writing, [only beta releases of Qt 5.10](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.10_Release) are available.*

Comment: Is it possible to use `Loader` for root element to recreate `sourceComponent` completely including all the user visible strings?

Comment: @Orient I don't know by hard. You should give it a try, but you will loose all state information that is stored inside qml.