# UpdateLanguage in translation in qt

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to updatelanguage in my code as shown below:

```
LanguageTranslation.h
    class LanguageTranslation : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PROPERTY(QString emptyString READ getEmptyString NOTIFY languageChanged)
        QTranslator translator;
        QQmlEngine *m_engine;
    
    public:
        explicit LanguageTranslation();
        QString getEmptyString();
    
        enum Language {
            ENGLISH,
            FRENCH
        };
    
        Q_ENUM(Language)
    
    signals:
        void languageChanged();
    
    public slots:
        void updatelanguage(int lang);
    
};


LanguageTranslation.cpp
#include "LanguageTranslation.h"

QString LanguageTranslation::getEmptyString()
{
    return "";
}

void LanguageTranslation::updatelanguage(int language)
{
    switch (language)
    {
    case ENGLISH :
        if(!translator.isEmpty())
            qApp->removeTranslator(&translator);
        translator.load("Monitor_en_US", ":/translations");
        qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
//        m_engine->retranslate();
        break;

    case FRENCH:
        translator.load("Monitor_fr_FR", ":/translations");
        qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
//        m_engine->retranslate();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    emit languageChanged();
}


Rectangle.qml
Rectangle
            {
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height * 0.20
                color: "red"
                Text {
                    width: parent.width
                    text: qsTrId("abcId")+ LanguageTranslation.emptyString

                }
            }
```

This text: qsTrId("abcId") is updating only when i am using

```
text: qsTrId("abcId") + LanguageTranslation.emptyString
```

Is there any other way to update the language other than appending emptyString??
I dont want to use emptyString to update the language. Also when i am using retranslate(), my application is crashing.

Comment: did you take a look at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351298/translate-qt-qml-application-on-the-fly

Comment: Why did you uncomment `m_engine->retranslate()`, you need to do that to let the engine know a new language was loaded

Comment: Using  m_engine->retranslate() in my code results in crashing of my application.  Is it happening because i am using QQmlApplicationEngine applicationEngine in main.cpp ??

Comment: it is strongly recommended not to name custom components as the system ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for updateLanguage using retranslate() as shown below:

```
void LanguageTranslation::upDateLanguage(int language)
{
    switch (language)
    {
    case ENGLISH :
        m_translator.load("Language_en_US", ":/translations");
        break;

    case FRENCH:
        m_translator.load("Language_fr_FR", ":/translations");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    qApp->installTranslator(&m_translator);
    m_engine->retranslate();
    emit languageChanged();

}
```